# Rspec testing not registering button with graphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am writing tests for my rails application and the Button itself is in a class called tick. In the test I have the following, but it fails.

```
click_button "tick"
```

This works for my other buttons such as:

```
click_button "Create School"
```

The tick button is a check mark, when I inspect element I see

```
<a class="tick" data=method="get" href="/tasks/1/edit">
  ::after
</a>
```

As a follow on, the data is presented as a table, so there are multiple ticks on the page, I am wondering if this is causing the issue. A little more close up of the inspect element shows:

```
<tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">school</td>
      <td>
         <a class="tick" data-method="get" href="/schools/16/edit">
            ::after
         </a>
         <a class="cross" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/schools/16">
            ::after
         </a>
      </td>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">school2</td>
      <td>
         <a class="tick" data-method="get" href="/schools/52/edit">
            ::after
         </a>
         <a class="cross" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/schools/52">
            ::after
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

What should the RSpec/Capybara test be looking for to click?

Comment: Do you want `click_link` instead of `click_button`?

Comment: No, it is a button and it works on the other buttons.

Comment: Your supplied HTML indicates that it is a link.

Comment: I tried it, but it still is saying can't find link tick.

Comment: If my updated answer doesn't solve your issue - pleaes add the exact error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara's `click_button` will find `<input>` elements (with type of `submit`, `reset`, `image`, `button`) and `<button>` elements. That method will not work on `<a>`. Rather, `#click_link` finds `<a>` elements with an href attribute that match a provided string - that string is matched against `id`, text content, `title`, or descendant `<img>` `alt` attribute. There is also `click_link_or_button` which will (as the name implies) try to match against links or buttons.

<s>From your question it appears the `<a>` element has text content of `::after` so</s> Since you've updated your question and every link is showing ::after in it - I'm going to assume that's actually the indiciation from your browser that a CSS pseudo element is being used with the element ( if that is not a correct assumption you can try `click_link('::after')` )

In the case where you may not have any of the `id`, text, `title`, or `alt` attributes to match against -- you'll need to use a plain finder and call `click` like the following examples (or add an id or title attribute to the elements).

```
find('a.tick').click
find('a[href=/schools/52/edit]').click
```

In your updated html if attempting to use the first of those examples you'll also need to scope your find to one of your rows so it can find a unique element

```
find('tr', text: 'school2').find('a.tick').click
```

Comment: Does it matter that its in a row?

Comment: I added more from the page, since there is multiple cross and tick buttons for editing and deleting each record. I posted it on the original post above.

Comment: Then you need to scope your finders - find('tr', text: 'school2').find('a.tick').click